# When aircraft rolls across airport field, uses its main engines or any kind of chassis gears?

Tags: aircraft-design

Taxiing, turns, approach to gates - everything is done without the loud sound of motors

Comment: It's unfortunate that this has been marked as a duplicate since I can't now add a different answer. Air India and Lufthansa are now making use of [taxibot](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/TaxiBot), an Israeli developed system employing a pilot-controlled, semi-autonomous tug to tow aircraft to and from the runway.

Comment: @CatchAsCatchCan If the OP is interested in that, they could edit their question to ask for alternatives and we could then vote to re-open the question. As it is right now, the question does not ask for alternative systems, so you should not answer.

Comment: @cathascatchcan you may add information on the other (original, not duplicate) question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Main Engines, and braking with wheel mechanical brakes.

Main engines at low power are used to move on the ground, that's why usually planes can't move backward, unless the engines are capable of reverse thrust.

And for ground maneuvering planes uses wheel brakes, as other land vehicles.

Comment: ofc, i will update it

Comment: Most larger aircraft (including regional propliners) _are_ capable of reverse thrust, but this is avoided because the wash potentially hurling heavy objects in front of the plane around and breaking terminal windows.